# What does mapping mean in entity framework?

Tags: mapping, entity-framework-5, terminology

I can't find the definition of mapping on google. What is the exact meaning of it?

Comment: Where are you seeing the reference?  In some online documentation?  Can you post a link to that documentation?

Comment: Good old Fowler: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for this, I understand it now. Can you create an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone bumping on the same problem I had take a look at Gert Arnold's comment.